# <Import statement issue>ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I recently started working the pandas library and had everything running alright. And then recently, each time I run a program, even a short one like what I have attached, it displays the error below. Can someone help me fix it?

Error:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code in the form of an image but rather use StackOverflow's code formatting feature. Refer to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9917504) for the why

Comment: Have you set the `venv`-python interpreter to be the one used in this project? If not do so under settings -> Project: Working with the pandas library -> Project Interpreter, and then add the one inside `venv` (You might have to select it by clicking on the small cog -> add)

Comment: Did you install numpy by running pip install numpy ?

Comment: Yes. I am using Jetbrains Pycharm Edu. So I installed NumPy using pip install NumPy, then later installed the NumPy library package within Pycharm. Could there be some problem with the way I installed it?